# Why can't I do cross-page posting with server form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I have a minimal website (based on the Visual Studio template).

I am trying to post my server-side form to a different aspx page by using the `action` attribute of the form. I keep getting the infamous `Invalid postback or callback argument` exception.

I can get it working if I use `PostBackUrl` attribute in my Button, but why can't I submit the form to a different page with the `action` attribute? I don't want to disable my event validation.

Below is my `Site.Master`.`Default.aspx` and `Contact.aspx` are totally empty (except using the master page). None of the pages have code-behind.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="LauriTest.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" action="Contact.aspx">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried to replicate your scenario. When I tried to submit to Contact.aspx, I have received "Validation MAC failed". I am not sure it is the same error that you have got. All I did to make it work (Cross page posting) is to disable the MAC Validation at Page directive of the Contact.aspx page. EnableViewStateMac="false"

Comment: No, I don't get MAC validation errors. I literally started a new asp.net project from the Visual Studio 2013 template, removed all bullshit and I was down to this. I have even restarted my computer to try to fix this strangeness, but no help. This is somehow related to the master-page setup, as I don't get the error if there's no master page involved.

Answer (score 0):

try adding  [`EnableEventValidation="false"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to your aspx page (first line `<%@ Page put-here-the parameter %>`)

second thing remember to put in your page load method

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack){//doOperation}
```

**update**

try registering control for event validation

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
  ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(YourButtonThatCausesSubmit.UniqueID.ToString());
  base.Render(writer);
}
```

**reason**

Event validation  check if the origin of the event cames from one rendered control previously loaded (and not some acked control). In rendering phase, events can be validated during postback with __doPostBack. In your case something is breaking this validation and the server think that postback comes from external objects, maybe some character, try this last attempt ( repace `<` and `>`) before submitting the form

```
var ok= OriginalString.replace("<","&lt;");
ok= ok.replace(">","&gt;");
return ok;
```

**Update2**

I see from your code that is the masterpage code. You are inserting a form element.
The page that inherit from your masterpage probably has another form. If yes, this is the reason of your error (more than one form).

Comment: I don't want to disable my event validation. Sorry, forgot to include in the original question. And as I said, I don't have any code in code-behind

Comment: Nope, doesn't help. `Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(test.UniqueID);` . Also, my question was mostly about "why" - I can get it working with `PostBackUrl` if needed.

Comment: last attempt, let me know

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not posting any strings. I don't even need to input anything in the textbox, I just leave it empty and I get the error.

Comment: I've done another update, let me know if it solve your problem

Comment: Dude. Are you reading my question? I clearly wrote that the other pages are empty - there's nothing in them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67331/discussion-between-faby-and-lauri-peltonen).

Comment: I can read. But your code comes from masterpage that must be used by aspx page. This page by default has a `form runat=server`. Did you remove it?